# How do I write this as a solution for hyperbolic sine and cosine?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions

Consider the following PDE. Where $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$

> $u_{tt}+u_t = u_{xx}$
>
> $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$
>
> $u(x,0)=0$
>
> $u_t(x,0)=10$

I am having trouble solving for my $T(t)$, it comes down to an ODE

So just to save some time and work, for my eigenfunctions, I got  $X_n(x) = \sin(nx)$ with $\lambda = n$.

> $T''+T'+n^2T = 0$
>
> $T(0)=0$
>
> $T'(0)=10$

Now I am having trouble writing my solution as hyperbolic functions. My roots from auxilarily equation is $r=\dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4n^2}}{2}$. Any idea on how to get rid of that $\frac{1}{2}$ in front?

Comment: In fact for any Telegraph-type equation, Klein-Gordon-type equation and Helmholtz-type equation, they both have the characteristic that you are impossible to accommodate all of the function parts of the independent variables to get the nice form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $n \geq 1$. Hence, $1-4n^2 < 0$. Let $1-4n^2 = -k_n^2$. This gives us that $r = -\dfrac12 \pm i\dfrac{k_n}2$. Then $T_n(t)$ is of the form
$$T_n(t) = \exp(-t/2) \left(A_n \cos(k_nt/2) + B_n \sin(k_n t/2) \right)$$ $T_n(0) = 0 \implies A_n = 0$. Hence, $$T_n(t) = B_n \exp(-t/2) \sin(k_n t/2)$$
$$T_n'(t) = -1/2 B_n \exp(-t/2) \sin(k_n t/2) + B_n k_n/2 \exp(-t/2) \cos(k_n t/2)$$
$$T_n'(0) = B_n k_n/2 = 10 \implies B_n = \dfrac{20}{k_n}$$
Hence, $$T_n(t) = \exp(-t/2) \dfrac{20 \sin(k_n t/2)}{k_n}$$

**EDIT**

Your final solution is now of the form
$$u(x,t) = 20 \exp(-t/2) \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(k_n t/2) \sin(nx)}{k_n} \right)$$

**EDIT**

If you get the roots as $r=a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then the solution is of the form $$c_1 \exp(at) + c_2 \exp(bt)$$ which can be rewritten as $$\exp \left(\dfrac{a+b}2t \right) \left(k_1 \cosh \left(\dfrac{(a-b)t}2 \right) + k_2 \sinh \left(\dfrac{(a-b)t}2 \right) \right)$$

Comment: Oh shoot, that was an oversight...now I have a very stupid question to follow. Suppose $0 < n < 1/4$, how do I write the solution in hyperbolic form?

Comment: @sizz Your $n$ is always $\geq 1$ since you need $X(\pi) = 0$. This gives us $\sin(n \pi) = 0 \implies n \in \mathbb{Z}$. $n=0$ gives the solution as $0$.

Comment: No, no, no, I know the restrictions on my 'n's, but now I am just solely interested in an eigenvalue problem where we get something like a distinct root like I mentioned and I want to write it as a hyperbolic sum